# SqlTransaction automatically disposed when Exception occurs

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I need to execute a bunch of INSERT queries inside a transaction and rollback everything if one of them fails, but I still need to execute them all, in order to have all error messages in one try.

I have something like this :

```
using (var myConn = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionManager.Instance.CurrentConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    myConn.Open();
    using (var myTransaction = myConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var req in myReqsToExecute)
            {
                using (var myCom = new SqlCommand(req.Request, myConn, myTransaction))
                {
                    try
                    {   
                        //Set parameters
                        ...
                        myCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var detail = "...";
                        errorMessages.Add("Erreur ExecuteSQL : " + ex.Message + " Details : " + detail.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (errorMessages.Any())                            
                myTransaction.Rollback();
            else
                myTransaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

It usually works well.
But if an `Exception` occurs and the error I have is `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.` (which may happen in a normal process), in the `catch` block, `myCom.Transaction` is set to `null` and the `SqlTransaction` seem to be disposed, so `myTransaction` cannot be used any more and any subsequent valid query executed is committed.

It looks like the transaction is automatically rollbacked but with any other error (at least the ones I tried), it behaves as expected (ie. I can rollback manually).

Comment: Define "any other error". Generally this is a database level issue and the db already failed the transaction in this case. Any other error may have been - well - C# level errors ;)

Comment: Columns that doesn't exist, invalid query (like I delete half of it), parameter missing... So both C# and Sql Server errors

Comment: A database transaction is meant to be atomic, i.e. all or nothing. So the behavior you are observing is as expected.. if you get a database error the whole transaction rolls back and you get that one exception since the rest of the records or commands are not executed or attempted..  You might want to check [this post](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/12/17/transactions-rolling-back-a-transaction/) which uses nested transactions which I think should help

Comment: But, why is it working with some errors (most) and not with this one ? Nowhere in the documentation it is mentionned that the transaction is auto rollbacked and disposed. And in all examples I see, people call Rollback on the transaction, which I can't as the transaction is already disposed.
This is an app that has been working like that for years without any issue. But this is a new type of error as now we are loading Excel files and the connector might not determine the correct datatype, this is why we never encountered it until now.